# Reviewboard error abort: The file was not found in the repository (207)

Tags: mercurial, review-board

Unable to see the differences in reviewboard. Seeing the below error while posting review. But in review board portal i can see the message. but couldnt see the differences.

```
[dkanagaraj@localhost hid-MS-PoC]$ hg postreview tip --debug
Parent is d63949c66c7a
Remote parent is None

=== Diff from parent to rev ===
diff -r d63949c66c7a0302f8f7495f5c1b62bfb2c0e92c -r 16487c0824fdd5bd124e3266a1055be321b13f37 RFP/hid-MS-PoC/rundev.bat
--- a/RFP/hid-MS-PoC/rundev.bat Mon Feb 15 14:59:19 2016 -0500
+++ b/RFP/hid-MS-PoC/rundev.bat Mon Feb 15 16:22:21 2016 -0500
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
-
+@REM
start cmd /k "cd portal& call rundev.bat"
start cmd /k "cd rfp& call rundev.bat"  


Changeset 72:16487c0824fd
---------------------------
changed rundev.bat for reviewboard

reviewboard:    http://10.129.47.15/reviews/

Looking for '10.129.47.15 /reviews/' cookie in /home/dkanagaraj/.post-review-cookies.txt
Loaded valid cookie -- no login required
Repositories:
[2] chennai_sis
repository id: 2
abort: The file was not found in the repository. (207)
stat: fail
file: RFP/hid-MS-PoC/rundev.bat
revision: d63949c66c7a0302f8f7495f5c1b62bfb2c0e92c
```

Below are from reviewboard logs which enabled in debug mode

```
2016-02-15 21:25:03,062 - INFO -  - Reloading logging settings
2016-02-15 21:25:03,067 - DEBUG -  - Cache miss for key jsi18n-djangojs-reviewboard_djblets-en-1449235847.
2016-02-15 21:25:03,255 - INFO -  - Reloading logging settings
2016-02-15 21:26:40,118 - INFO -  - Reloading logging settings
2016-02-15 21:26:40,136 - INFO -  - Reloading logging settings
2016-02-15 21:26:40,174 - INFO -  - Reloading logging settings
2016-02-15 21:26:40,227 - INFO -  - Reloading logging settings
2016-02-15 21:26:40,245 - DEBUG -  - DiffParser.parse: Beginning parse of diff, size = 357
2016-02-15 21:26:40,245 - DEBUG -  - DiffParser.parse: Finished parsing diff.
2016-02-15 21:26:40,297 - DEBUG -  - Using rbssh for mercurial
```

Comment: This can happen if the parent review (d63949c66c7a) is not in the remote repository, either because it hasn't been pushed or because it's an MQ patch.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me, and it took me ages to find out why. What made the difference was having this in my home .hgrc file:

```
[mq]
secret = true
```

Whenever I qpushed a patch, this made the phase of the patch's commit "secret".  That stopped it showing up in `hg out` as well as breaking Review Board.

Taking the line out of my `.hgrc` made it work again. You may have to change the phase of the patches you already have pushed, either with `hg phase` or by qpopping and qpushing them.

Answer (score -1):

`hg postreview -l` it can be resolved by adding long diff.

Comment: Can you explain that further? What does "by adding long diff" mean? How does one achieve that?

Comment: My 'hg' doesn't seem to have a subcommand called 'postreview'.